# Simplifying Bernoulli/Indicator Variables into Closed form

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I am calculating the probability that in $2n$ coin flips, there is a greater number of heads than there are tails.
By using binomial distribution, I came up with the following answer:

$$\sum_{i=n+1}^{2n} \binom{2n}{i} (\frac{1}{2})^{2n} $$

Is there perhaps a better way to reach this solution in a closed form?

Comment: Sometimes a simpler form is obtained by thinking about the complementary event.  Here (assuming a "fair" coin), the chance of a greater number of heads should equal that of a greater number of tails.  However the count of $2n$ coin flips allows for an equal number of heads and tails, so the probability you seek is not quite half.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

- $\binom{2n}{i} = \binom{2n}{2n - i}$
- $\binom{2n}{0} + \binom{2n}{1} + \cdots + \binom{2n}{2n} = 2^{2n}$